# How to access aspx control in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

NET. i am trying to access the div tag in code behind which is inside the `SeparatorTemplate` 
Here is my aspx code

```
<div>
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
        <ItemStyle ForeColor="#4A3C8C" BackColor="#E7E7FF"></ItemStyle>
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table width="900px">
                <tr>
                    <td width="300px">
                        <b>Name</b>
                    </td>
                    <td width="300px">
                        <b>Account No</b>
                    </td>
                    <td width="300px">
                        <b>Company</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table width="900px">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" width="300px">
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name")%>
                    </td>
                    <td align="left" width="300px">
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AccountNo")%>
                    </td>
                    <td align="left" width="300px">
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Company")%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" BackColor="#4A3C8C"></HeaderStyle>
        <SeparatorTemplate>
            <div id="divSeprator" runat="server">//This div tag i want to access in the code behind  
            <br />
            </div>

        </SeparatorTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
</div>
```

I have tried accessing the `this.Controls` and `DataList1.Controls` but both of those doesn't contain this div i know it is in the `SepratorTemplate` but i don't know how to access control from that template because there is nothing to find the controls.

Comment: what are you attempting to accomplish?

Comment: Actually i am trying to apply the separator template after 2 rows not after each row so i want to check condition in the code behind and apply the div tag according to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    // Find the div control as htmlgenericcontrol type, if found apply style
    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div =  (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("DivContent");

    if(div != null)
        div.Style.Add("border-color", "Red");

}
```

Comment: Would be better to add check for `e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Separator` to avoid NullReferenceException or use `as` syntax for type casting

Answer (score 0):

You will need to find it from the datalist row as below.

```
HtmlGenericControl div = (HtmlGenericControl)yourDataList.Items[0].FindControl("dvSeparator");
```

You can pass the index of the data list item (row) in `.Items[]` for which you want to find the div for processing.

If you want to process div from all the datalist items then you can do it in the item data bound event of the datalist as @Upvote MarkAnswer has suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
HtmlGenericControl divSeprator = (HtmlGenericControl)DataList1.Items[0].FindControl("divSeprator");
```

Where **0** is your item index.

Or just bind a **DataList1_ItemDataBoud** event and use:

```
if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Separator)
   HtmlGenericControl divSeprator = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("divSeprator");
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to make  tag runat="sever" and give it id

```
<div id="div" runat="server">
```

Then you can access it by using

```
HtmlGenericControl div = HtmlGenericControl("div")
```

Comment: This won't complile, as `HtmlGenericControl("div")` is not a function. You will need to find control from the datalist or parent datalist item.